# How to make domain url lead to index.html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

How can i make that with entering mywebsite.com it leads to mywebsite.com/index.html?

I'm using siteground and I was recommended htacess but I'm really new at web programming, I don't know what that is and I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

In the Root folder of your website (on the server itself) is a file named .htaccess
That file contains information for the server, about which files and folders are accessable from the internet.
.htaccess can only be accessed when you are logged into your server account. It is a textfile in the Root folder of your hosting area.
In the file you can route all incoming traffic to index.php or index.html or whatever you like.
Here is some more info https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: theres no .htaccess file, should i create it then?

Comment: Yes you can, if you want the redirect, Siteground has some info https://www.siteground.com/kb/url_masking_with_htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create .htaccess file in the directory of the website.
Inside it, at its very top, you should add:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

That will lead anyone to yoursite/index.html.